# UITableViewCell's reuse identifier not recognized only when launching from RESideMenu

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[Here is the link to RESideMenu, what I'm using in my project](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)

To put it simply, when I make my UITableView the root viewcontroller and launch it, it works just fine. All my custom UITableViewCells are there and look great. The issue is, whenever I try and launch the UITableView from the RESideMenu. When I do, I get this error:

```
2013-07-06 11:49:07.844 halocustoms[4438:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:4460 2013-07-06 11:49:07.845 projectcf32[4438:c07] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CustomCell -
must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I have checked my reuse identifier on my Storyboard about a hundred times, and it must work because when the app launches initially everything is fine. It's just when selecting the UITableViewController from the RESideMenu.

Note, this is how RESideMenu displays the viewcontroller:

```
RESideMenuItem *homeItem = [[RESideMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quick Games" action:^(RESideMenu *menu, RESideMenuItem *item) {
        [menu hide];

        MyTableView *viewController = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
        viewController.title = item.title;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
        [menu setRootViewController:navigationController];
    }];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, how did you implement RESIDEMENU with Storyboard?

Comment: I gave up, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hi there. Me neither at the moment. I have found some simpler way of implementing this. It has not so many options but it works with storyboard. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ios7menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyTableView *viewController = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
```

should be:

```
MyTableView *viewController = (MyTableView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"yourIdentifier"];
```